# A better jQuery Scrollspy plugin

Tags: jquery

I am searching everywhere for a better scrollspy plugin.

Why do I need better? The existing solutions are either unmaintained/buggy or not flexible enough to be used anywhere

Is there a jQuery scrollspy plugin out there that is actively maintained and is usable?

Some more specifics:

- Bootstrap scrollspy requires #ids, to use their own classes and is very limited.

I just want a scrollspy that is not buggy (many are unmaintained). Basic requirements:

- Bind an element to an event that when the element is visible, a callback would fire
- when the element disappears another callback would fire
- ability to use offset (like only appear on half the height)
- handling resizing of the window (most plugins need to recalculate heights manually when there is a resize of the browser window)
- and an important bind - won't force me to use anything special for page layout (no `.nav`, `#id`) and to be able to have several of those instances on screen/in a parent div

I realize this is not a hard plugin to create, I just don't have time to perfect it to a usable, production-ready state.

I searched for scrollspy, scrollpeak, scrollwatch, anchorific, tocify  - most are unmaintained, and the last two are either too bloated with useless (for me) functionality or force me to use some special layout

Comment: Can you define *is usable*

Comment: Have you found anything good yet?